# How do I get a specific CSS value in Pixate programmatically?

Tags: ios, pixate

Is there a way to get values from Pixate programmatically? I'd like to be able to get a CSS value for a specific id, class, or element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example on how to get a view tint color. Any property name will work instead of course.

```
PXStylesheet *currentSheet = [PixateFreestyle currentApplicationStylesheet];
PXRuleSet *rules           = [currentSheet ruleSetsMatchingStyleable:view][0];
PXDeclaration * decl       = [rules declarationForName:@"-ios-tint-color"];
UIColor *color             = decl.colorValue;
```

A few things to note,

- You can have more than 1 style sheet. User, view, and application. Use [PXRuleSet ruleSetWithMergedRuleSets:rules] if this is the case
- ruleSetsMatchingStyleable: is a private call. You need to include PXStylesheet-Private.h
- In my example I only had 1 rule set. You may have more so you probably want to iterate the response of ruleSetsMatchingStyleable: .